# Chrome throws an URL error when I type in a file path (p5js)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am loading images from files on a p5.js and there is an error through from the browser (yes, all of them) that says:

```
URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
```

My code looks like this:

```
let img;
let x = 200;
let y = 200;

function preload() {
    img = loadImage("spirites/OPI.jpg");
}
function setup() {
createCanvas(400, 400);
image(img, 200, 200, 200, 200);
}

function draw() {

}
```

I don't know how to load the image. I tried putting the full image path, still didn't work, I tried Putting `file:\\\` in front of it, but to no prevail. Why isn't this working?

Comment: I rolled back your question. You should not massively change it after it received an answer because doing so invalidates the answer. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: @c0d3r Do you use a web server to statically serve the html and js files ? (If so you could use something like `loadImage("/spirites/OPI.jpg");`. Checkout the [p5.js local server reference](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server)

Answer (score 2):

The errors is trying to tell you that you cannot load a `file://` URL over CORS. You can only load `http://` and `https://` URLs. This is for security reasons, otherwise the page could scan your whole computer and look at all your files, if some malicious script was loaded in it...

So, you should probably run a local server and serve your application from there. [Mongoose](https://www.cesanta.com/binary.html) could be an easy start (you only need the free version - drop it into the project folder and start it; you can close it again from the systray icon), or maybe [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/). Then you could load your file normally, relative to your page or the project root.

Comment: Is there any way to load an image from a file. It is important that I do this.

Comment: No. As I said, you should probably serve your application using a local server, then you can place the file somewhere inside the project folder and access it over HTTP, e.g. `http://localhost/spirites/OPI.jpg`. (I mean, yes there is the [HTML5 File API](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5/file-api.html) but it sounds to me based on your question like this is not the direction you need to go to, since this is very specifically for the user to grant access to certain local folders.)

Comment: How do i set up Caddy for my system (windows)\

Comment: Mongoose is simpler. But for Caddy you can just run it with the `file-server` command: https://caddyserver.com/docs/command-line#caddy-file-server - for example `caddy file-server --root c:\users\user\myProject --listen :3000` and then your application is served at http://localhost:3000/

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: I staarted up the exicutable for Mongoose but all it pulls up is a blank browser page.

Comment: No it starts a server. The server will keep running until you close it (you see it in your systray). The page in the browser is your application's index.html. Probably you have a JavaScript error or incorrect file path now (maybe you had an absolute path in the code before) so it looks empty. You should check your browser's devtools for error messages and fix them.

Comment: do i put the exicutable in the folder with the code or the sprites folder

Comment: Where do i put the mongoose exicutable